# Aliasing _id in an FTS3 database

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, fts3

My application uses an SQLite database with FTS3. The results of a query shall be displayed in a list view using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. However I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist`

Doing some search I found this answer:
[Android Full Text Search and ListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011405/android-full-text-search-and-listadapter/5083602#5083602). I get the point but I can't figure out how to create this alias for `docid -> _id`. The SearchableDictionary example on the Android pages are not that helpful for me ;-)

Cheers,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a 'raw' query such as...

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT docid as _id,...");
```